# Where to put big files if not in repo?

Tags: git, drupal-7

We use Drupal for a lot of our development, and we often include the /sites folder when committing it to the repo. But this isn't really possible for seriously big sites. I mean, you can't save a 1GB video file in your GitHub repo. We are hitting the limit on images mostly. Repos are getting very big because of all the content being uploaded and being stored in /sites/.

If I do not include these files in the repos, then developers can't see the pages properly, as content will be missing. If I link directly to the server, it will be slower to get content and not work 100% offline.

So what is the best way to deal with keeping your big media files in a repo? Is there a way to somehow "offload" parts? Or should you perhaps keep two repos, one for the user content and one for the code?

Any tips on how to get around this git problem will be great! I want to avoid increasing the size of my repo (so it only has code), but not miss out on user content changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue several times.

Simplest solution I found is to keep /files directory out of repos. Every developer will have a custom /files for local debugging.

A couple of far more complex solution are:

- Write some custom code to be used for developement which replace "local path to /files" with "production path to /files" (read only)
- Share Filesystem containing production /files (carefully here, this is risky!)

Also, you will need of course to define some backup strategy for your files.

Comment: I think that is what we are going to do. Remove /sites from the repo, and always directly link to files on production... but then we obviously lose out on having the entire site locally.

Comment: There's probably no point in having good the entire site locally.  Au contrarie,  when having many developers,  it could be an issue, actually.

Comment: Imagine a site with a forum, and lots of people posting images. Each time you have to debug something on some forum page, you would have to download all the images for the newly added content.

Comment: I see. It would be like this: A). On the production directory, create a files_for_debugging directory aside /file B). Add this new directory to the repository. C) copy files for debug into this new directory  D) commit E) update development with this new directory,  F) in development,  delete files  and  create a link  /files   pointing to the local /files_for_debugging